# How to prove the method which returns IEnumerable has been called twice?

Tags: c#

In Visual Studio, ReSharper warns: "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable" for the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<string> items = Test2();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    var newitems = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        newitems.Append(item);
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<string> Test2()
{
    string[] array1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
    return array1;
}
```

I expect that the Test2 method will be called twice, but it's called once.

What am I missing?

Comment: The method is called once, but the array is iterated twice. That's not a problem in this case, but sometimes it is (for example, if the enumerable lazily fetched data from a website)

Comment: How to see the array was iterated twice?

Comment: you're looping through the same array twice. why not just populate your `StringBuilder` in the first `foreach` loop?

Comment: An array is a collection so it's not only a "query" which will be evaluated always. It is not using deferred execution. But if the method [`yielded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) the items it would be using deferred execution and resharper would be right. Since you have declared a `IEnumerable<string>` it's always possible that the implementation of the method changes to return the items lazily. That's why the recommendation of resharper is valid anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's only called once because `Test2()` actually returns `string []` which is also an `IEnumerable<string>.` 
This `string []` array remains referenced by `items` so  each time you use  `items` you just re-use the array.

The case you're expecting is an implementation of `Test2()` with an [iterator block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) :

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Test2()
{
    string[] array1 = { "1", "2", "3" };

    foreach (var str in array1) 
    {
        yield return str; 
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here are the docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Possible+multiple+enumeration+of+IEnumerable) for this warning, confirming it's more about the fact it might go to the source more than once.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this example:

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<int> items = Test2();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    var newitems = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        newitems.Append(item);
    }
}

IEnumerable<int> Test2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test2 called");
    return GetEnum();
}

IEnumerable<int> GetEnum()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing work...");
        Thread.Sleep(50); //Download some information from a website, or from a database
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Imagine that `return GetEnum();` was `return new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }`

Now, with arrays, iterating them multiple times isn't necessarily a bad thing. In your case, you can do the work in one loop, but that's not the reason resharper warns you. It warns you because of the possibility that `Test2()` returns a lazy enumerable that *does work* every time it's iterated.

If you run the above code, you'll get this output:

```
Test2 called
Doing work...
0
Doing work...
1
Doing work...
2
Doing work...
3
Doing work...
4
Doing work...
Doing work...
Doing work...
Doing work...
Doing work...
```

Note that `Test2` itself is only called once, but the enumerable is iterated twice (and the work is done twice!).

You can avoid this by writing:

```
var items = Test2().ToList();
```

Which will immediately evaluate the enumerable and put it into a list. In this case, the work is only done *once*.

Comment: _"In this case, the work is only done once."_ With the caveat that the whole of the processing must be done at once and everything held in memory, rather than being able to process the items one at a time as they're available.  +1, nevertheless...

Answer (score 1):

As many pointed out, the purpose of this warning is to point out that an expensive operation may be happening more than once. This happens because ReSharper sees that your method returns a IEnumerable which could lead to lazy evaluation, if you where using yield returns or most LINQ methods.

ReSharper stops warning about multiple evaluation when it can know for sure that the thing you are iterating over is a collection. You can provide that information to ReSharper in 2 ways.

1. Change the return type of Test2 to `IList<string>`
2. Before the first
   `foreach` add `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(items is
   IList<string>);`

If you use `ToList()` over the returned `IEnumerable<string>` ReSharper will also know that you are iterating over a collection, but you would also be creating an unnecessary temporary list (you already had an array), paying the cost of time and memory to build that new list.

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable<T>` is an interface that has an enumerator that will be called every time you want to access your collection of data (the foreach loops). Resharper warns you that if your data is not ordered, and you call this enumerator on the dataset multiple times, then the runtime will probably need to go through your collection multiple times which can put load and slow down execution time.

In order to avoid that you can cast your dataset to an ordered collection first: e.g. call .ToArray() or .ToList() on your items variable.